# What is the Correct Way to Scale then Rotate a set of Points?

Tags: scale, linear-algebra, scaling, coordinate-transformation, scaletransform

I have 4 points, point **A**(x1, y1), point **B**(x2, y1), and point **C**(x2, y2), point **D**(x2, y3) creating two scales: Scale1 yRange(**B**, **D**), Scale2 yRange(**B, C**).

[image]

I want to scale the y axis only, so that point **D** is scaled down to point **C**, so that the angle between **CAB** is a certain degree. Then I want to rotate the scaled point **C** around point **B** a certain degree, obtaining point **E**. Then I want to find the real value of point **E** on the un-scaled coordinate grid where original point **D** is located. I think I need to use affine transformations, but all examples are rotate first, then scale. But I need to scale first, then rotate. How do I find this new value? I know how to perform rotations alone and a bit of scaling alone, but not together.

Maybe I am confused, after I perform the scaling and rotation, I would not need to scale back, because the new value of **E** equates to **F**? I know there are plenty of examples, but I can not wrap my head around this...

Here is my objective. I have the 3 points **A**, **B** and **D**. I want to scale so that **DAB** equates to let's say 60 degrees, creating point **C**, then perform several point rotations on **C** inside the scaled grid. I ultimately want to find the value of **F**, and the other rotated points, which lies in geometrical positions inside the original unscaled grid that I can not calculate unless I scale the 3 original points to said degree first. The scaled grid contains the correct ratio I need in order to rotate my points. I need to do all my rotations inside the scaled grid, without losing values, but changing aspect ratio, and then take those new points inside the scaled grid and plot them in the unscaled grid, which will then lose correct aspect ratios, which is fine.

Coding in python.

Comment: So are you scaling d along the y-axis, rotating it around B and then scaling it back along the y-axis?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Python3 program that I think does what you want:

```
import math

# Use a negative angle since we're rotating clockwise
rotate_C_angle = math.radians(-60)

A = [0, 0]
B = [100, 0]
D = [100, 250]

# Create point D such that angle CAB = target_angle_CAB
target_angle_CAB = math.radians(60)
C = [B[0], B[0] * math.tan(target_angle_CAB)]

# What do we scale B by in order to get C
scale_factor = C[1] / D[1]

# Rotate C around B by rotate_C_angle
# (translate C by -Bx, then rotate, then translate back)
E = [
    C[0] - C[1] * math.sin(rotate_C_angle),
    C[1] * math.cos(rotate_C_angle)
]

# Scale E back
F = [E[0], E[1] / scale_factor]
```

This is assuming that A is at the origin. If it isn't then subtract Ax from all the x coordinates and Ay from the y coordinates, then do the calculations before translating back again.

Whether you need to scale back E to F depends on what you're doing. What happens here assumes that the scaling transformation along y does not get rotated.